# How to replace styles?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document in which I have text styles like Heading1, Heading2 etc.

I have specific formatting styles for each of these, I want to apply those styles.

Also I want to check if the correct styles were used.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do this with VBA Macros. But SO isn't here to provide solutions it here to help you. Maybe considering reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I understand that. I didn't want a solution either, but maybe if someone like yourself could point me out in the right direction.

Comment: What version of Microsoft Word do yo use? Did you know that you can "record" macros. That would be a point to start with. If specific problems occur feel free to update your question. Also I would like to know WHY you want to apply specific formatting's? I would like to understand your use case.

Comment: I use 2013. And yes, I know I can record macros. I am a professional VBA developer. But most of these macros that I created were in Excel. Now some of my clients send me these unformatted Word documents that I need to format in a particular style. So, I want to create a tool to check if any element is out of style.

Comment: Is it helpful what I've posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to what I understood from your question you would like to automatically replace styles.

Here is a macro which can help you doing that:

```
Public Sub SearchReplaceStyles()

Dim search_style As String ' the style which apparently seem out of style
Dim replace_style As String ' the desired style

search_style = "Heading 1"
replace_style = "Heading 2"

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(search_style)
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(replace_style)
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you want to check for formatting. But I'm sure if you're VBA Developer you'll figure it out quite fast.